# Linux multiline command with for

Tags: linux, loops, file

I want to test and compare files in two folders. For this purpose, I used the next command

```
for FILE in folder_one/*; do
    test -f folder_one_arch/$FILE && echo $FILE " exists" || echo $FILE " not exists"
    cmp -s $FILE folder_one_arch/$FILE && echo "same" || echo "different";
done
```

but this command is not working, from where is the problem occuring?

Comment: You want to compare `folder_one/a.txt` to `folder_one_arch/a.txt`?

Comment: FILE contains the leading `folder_one`.  (Why would you use the word "folder" in the name of a directory?!). Perhaps you want to use `${FILE#folder_one/}` to remove that prefix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from `$FILE`: it contains a path while you were expecting a file.

I propose you the following approach: have two variables, `PATH` which is the variable in the `for` loop and `FILE` which is only the file basename.

```sh
for PATH in folder_one/*; do
    echo "PATH is $PATH "
    FILE=${PATH##*/}
    echo "FILE is now $FILE"
    test -f folder_one_arch/$FILE && echo $FILE " exists" || echo $FILE " not exists"
    cmp -s $PATH folder_one_arch/$FILE && echo "same" || echo "different";
done
```

See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073